# Date_Diff not returning desired result

Tags: php, date, datediff, laravel-4.2

I am a bit confused i am using date_diff to get the days difference in -/+ integer I can only get +days even though it should be -days when the 2nd date is higher than 1st date.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2018-01-09");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2018-09-08");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
dd($interval->format('%R%a days'));
```

result

```
string(9) "+242 days"
```

it should be -21 days since date1 is behind by date2 .

Comment: Should that not be `->format(...)` (with a hyphen before the greater-than)?

Comment: It's a bit confusing with all the various function usage. What are the two dates you're trying to get the difference between?

Comment: Lets say the date today is the 1st date and 2nd date is 09-09-2018.

Comment: Simplifying your code a little (using `DateTime` constructors instead of all those functions), I cannot reproduce this ~ https://3v4l.org/YSkbf

Answer (score 2):

Check This output will not confuse you it will give correct output small change to your code

```php
// for negative difference output is -31days and date should be in yy-m-d format
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2018-02-01");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2018-01-01");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
printf($interval->format('%R%a days'));

echo "<br>";

// for positive difference output is +31days and date should be in yy-m-d format
$datetime3 = new DateTime("2018-01-01");
$datetime4 = new DateTime("2018-02-01");
$interval = $datetime3->diff($datetime4);
printf($interval->format('%R%a days'));

//bellow is output i get which is correct
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I'm editing my answer because I think there is a typo in your question when you say **-21 days** and not **-241 days**.

So, the standard for DateTime is 'Y-m-d'.

The difference between the dates will be calculated like this:

```
$firstDate = new DateTime('2018-01-10');
$secondDate = new DateTime('2018-01-15');
$firstDate->diff($secondDate);
```

Which can be translated as:

```
$secondDate - $firstDate;
```